# Is Kṛṣṇasāra mentioned in Manusmṛti 2.23 the spotted deer (Axis axis) or the blackbuck (Indian antelope)?

Tags: history, animals, manu-smriti, india, geography

Ganganath Jha [translates](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145599.html) 'kṛṣṇasāra' as 'spotted deer':

> **kṛṣṇasāra**stu carati mṛgo yatra svabhāvataḥ | 
>   sa jñeyo yajñiyo deśo mlecchadeśastvataḥ paraḥ || 23 ||
>
> But the region where the **spotted deer** roams by nature is to be known as the ‘land fit for sacrificial acts’; beyond that is the ‘land of the Mlecchas.’ (23)

But is it really the [spotted deer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chital) (*Axis axis*) which is spotted but not really black (kṛṣṇa)?

[image: spotted deer]

Or is it the [blackbuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbuck) (Indian antelope, *Antilope cervicapra*) which is black but not spotted?

[image: blackbuck]

**Note**: I'm looking for a comprehensive answer; not alternate translations.

Comment: It is the Blackbuck.

Answer (score 1):

In the Sanskrit dictionary, the word is used for spotted antelope.
[image]
So obviously it is chital or axis axis.[image]

Comment: Please read the note in my question, "Note: I'm looking for a comprehensive answer; not alternate translations."...In your question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38381/does-south-india-comes-within-land-of-mlechhas) you quote, "That land where the black antelope naturally roams"..so which one is it and why?